# Why does my Racket pen draw extra pixels where two lines join despite using 'butt and 'miter?

Tags: racket, pen, miter

I'm making two squares as seen in the following image.[One red and one blue square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxT1f.png)

The yellow circle is not part of the image, but it shows some pixels that I'm expecting to not be there. I have no experience with computer graphics, but from what I've read in the documentation, these pixels should not be there. Do I have unrealistic expectations or am I doing something wrong to get these 'overflow' pixels as shown by the yellow circle in my above drawing?

Here is the code that generates the boxes.

```
     #lang racket/gui

(define dc (new svg-dc%  
                [width 64]
                [height 64]
                [output "boxes.svg"]
                [exists 'replace]))
(send dc start-doc "boxes.svg")
(send dc start-page)

        (define old-brush (send dc get-brush))
        (define old-pen (send dc get-pen))
        (send dc set-brush 
          (new brush% [style 'solid]
                      [color "White"]))
        (send dc set-pen 
          (new pen% [width 0]
                    [color "Black"]
                    [cap 'butt]
                    [join 'miter]))
        (send dc set-pen old-pen)
        (send dc set-brush old-brush)   

        (send dc set-pen
          (new pen% [width 0]
                    [color "Black"]
                    [cap 'butt]
                    [join 'miter]))
        (send dc set-brush 
          (new brush% [style 'solid]
                      [color "Red"]))
        (define path (new dc-path%))
        (send path move-to 0 0)
        (send path line-to 10 0)
        (send path line-to 10 10)
        (send path line-to 0 10)
        (send path close)
        (send dc draw-path path 0 0)
        (send dc set-pen old-pen)
        (send dc set-brush old-brush)

        (send dc set-pen 
          (new pen% [width 0]
                    [color "Black"]
                    [cap 'butt]
                    [join 'miter]))
        (send dc set-brush
          (new brush% [style 'solid]
                      [color "Blue"]))
        (define path2 (new dc-path%))
        (send path2 move-to 0 0)
        (send path2 line-to 10 0)
        (send path2 line-to 10 10)
        (send path2 line-to 0 10)
        (send path2 close)
        (send dc draw-path path2 10 0)
        (send dc set-pen old-pen)
        (send dc set-brush old-brush)

(send dc end-page)
(send dc end-doc)
```

Comment: Can you post a complete example, we can try?

Comment: I have updated the post so that one can copy and paste the code portion to generate the image. I have not yet tried the suggestions in the answers section, but I will attempt them soon when time permits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a comment, but I needed some more space.

Things to look out for:

```
anti aliasing  - turn it of
smoothing      - is the mode unsmoothed or aligned?
```

Let's say the first pixel has opposite corners (0,0) and (1,1).
Without aligment, you can choose a square pen of size and
make a dot at (0.5,0.5) in order not to draw outside the pixel.

If things are aligned, you need to adjust accordingly.

See `set-smoothing`.

[https://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/dc___.html#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._racket%2Fdraw..rkt%29._dc~3c~25~3e%29._set-smoothing%29%29](https://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/dc___.html#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._racket%2Fdraw..rkt%29._dc%7E3c%7E25%7E3e%29._set-smoothing%29%29)

UPDATE

As far as I can tell, adding the line:

```
(send dc set-smoothing 'aligned)
```

at the beginning will fix the problem.

Comment: Initially tested (send dc set-smoothing 'unsmoothed) because 'smoothed and 'aligned are smoothing modes that enable anti-aliasing, but unfortunately, the output was the same.
The same output occurred when I tested the 'aligned mode, but the smudge seemed to go away when I tested the output while using the 'smoothed mode; that is, (send dc set-smoothing 'smoothed) fixed the issue. Can you share some ideas as to why an anti-aliased mode helped? What are some keywords to search to find an introduction to anti-aliasing (recall, beginner to computer graphics, but I am not afraid of mathematics.)

Comment: Since you were talking about pixels, I was expecting you to draw on a bitmap (or canvas) and then save as, say png. For SVG which is a vector format, I am a bit unsure whether antialaising has an effect. Suppose you want to draw a line from point A to B with a non-zero slope. If you zoom in, you will se a stair case effect. Filling in the stair case with grey pixels will create the illusion of a smoother line.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3AgvpOA2qw